# Lag on all videos *except* YouTube

Tags: linux, video, lag

I'm on Linux Mint 16, and have never had a problem like this before. I'm getting *severe* lag on all video streaming sites *except* for YouTube. By 'severe', I mean 'lags multiple times per second, completely unwatchable'.

I don't have issues with my Internet (speed tests run at about the same as what I'd usually get), and this is the first time I've had such a problem. I don't seem to have memory shortages (`top` didn't show anything unusual). I've also been getting the same problem with Pandora today (horrid lag).

Any advice as to where I should start looking for a solution?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using HTML5 video on YouTube instead of Flash?  That would explain why it doesn't lag like everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possibilities for the problem.

It could be an issue with your ISP throttling certain locations.  I guess you could do a tcpdump or use some other realtime bandwidth monitoring tool like iptraf to get a feel for if its the data arriving at your system.

It could be an issue with a library or flash (it might be you are not using Flash with Youtube)

Rather then run top, try running vmstat 2 to monitor more aspects of IO.

It is conceivable its an issue with your video driver.  What happens if you download the file and try to watch it ?

Does the problem only happen from this device, and if so, does it happen on all browsers ?